GitHub Devcontainers - Enable Communication between a Frontend (Angular) and a Backend (.NET)
Imagine a very simple scenario: You have a repository with a Frontend (let's say Angular) and a Backend (.NET).
The repository is also using devcontainers to have almost zero onboarding time.
If you would check out the repo locally: You can run the backend via http://localhost:5121. The Angular frontend runs on http://localhost:4200.
If you run those two inside the devcontainer, they also register themselves with this URL's (and also correctly expose the port).
Now, if your github devcontainer is called "cool-cobra-abcd" then the frontend is exposed via http://cool-cobra-abcd-4200.app.github.dev and the backend: http://cool-cobra-abcd-5121.app.github.dev
I would like to "pass" in the backend URL (http://cool-cobra-abcd-5121.app.github.dev) to the frontend as "http://localhost:5121" doesn't work. So an enviornment.ts like this will not work out of the box:
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  server: `http://localhost:5121/`,
};

Given that people might want to work locally, I don't want to put in "devcontainer-ish" stuff inside my configuration.
I also tried to expose the .NET backend via http://0.0.0.0/ and listen to this in my Angular Application without success.
What am I missing?
